# How to prevent layout from automatically opening keyboard?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using [MaterialChipsInput](https://github.com/Djyoyo/MaterialChipsInput). I have the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tile_divider2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/header" />

    <com.pchmn.materialchips.ChipsInput
        android:id="@+id/chips1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chip_backgroundColor="@color/primaryColor"
        app:chip_deletable="true"
        app:chip_hasAvatarIcon="false"
        app:chip_labelColor="@color/whiteColor"
        app:showChipDetailed="false"
        app:hint="@string/hint" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the java code is:

```
        chipsInput = (ChipsInput) findViewById(R.id.chips1);
        chipsInput.addChipsListener(new ChipsInput.ChipsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChipAdded(ChipInterface chip, int newSize) {}

            @Override
            public void onChipRemoved(ChipInterface chip, int newSize) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text) {
                if (text != null && text.toString().contains(" ") && text.toString().length() > 1) {
                    final String tag = StringUtils.capitalizeFully(text.toString().replaceAll(" ","").trim());
                    if (!(tag.isEmpty())) {
                        chipsInput.addChip(tag, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

For some reason, when I move to the activity and it loads the layout with that component, it automatically opens a keyboard on the `ChipsInput`. What could be the reason and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do for example:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Or

```
<activity
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        ...
        >
```

Another thing to try

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateHidden</item>
</style>

<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Add these two properties to your parent layout (ex: Linear Layout, Relative Layout)

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your widget(com.pchmn.materialchips.ChipsInput) is the first widget in Activity, there is a focus on this widget.

To solve this problem, you need to turn off the focus so that the keyboard does not open when the activity starts

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Manifest in tag current activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```